# Uiautomatorviewer, I am getting this error:

Tags: java, android-studio, automation, sdk, mobile-application

-Djava.ext.dirs=..\lib\x86_64;..\lib is not supported.  Use -classpath instead.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

C:\Users\s58887\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin>

I have set up the path for android home and java home

java version "13.0.2"